# Adding style-sheet to Vue.js component WITHOUT using Vue-CLI

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, components

I'm new to Vue.js and I like the idea behind the system to be good for both small and large complexity projects (the so called "Progressive" approach). However I think one thing breaks away from this approach: the style-sheets.

What I mean: as the title suggest, my problem is about using (or rather NOT using) Vue-CLI. I've read Vue-CLI is used when your Vue.js project starts to enter "large complexity" zone. For simpler use cases using only Vue class and its methods is enough: you can write code form `<template>` section of `.vue` file into `template` property of Vue component and the `<script>` section goes... well, into the script.

But what about `<style>` section? How can I add styles to my component? I suspect the solution may be not as "clean" as using Single File Components, but I think I may get my hands a little "dirtier". In Vanilla.js you can add `<style>` tag inside your template code in Web Components, but what about Vue?

Comment: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/single-file-components.html  Single file components allow for the related styles to also be included.  However, nothing will stop you from injecting a normal css page on your index.html that would/should affect everything.